# Ajax success function not being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and trying to implemented a JQUERY ajax post method. Here I am sending the data to another url through AJAX. all is working fine, api is getting all data but success event is not working in my code. I tried to alert the response but not getting anything. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (agent_id == "45") {
        $.ajax({       
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "TEXT",
            url: "http://pqrst.com/pqr/api/api.php",
            data: 'task='+ task+'&name='+name+'&emailid='+emailid+'&city='+city+'&country_phonecode='+country_phonecode+'&phone='+phone,
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {   
                alert(response);        
                //window.location = "http://lmno.com/thanks.php";
            }   
        });
    }
    else {
        window.location = "http://lmno.com/thanks1.php";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: add a handler for `error` too, maybe the call is not succesfull

Comment: can you see the POST request being fired, in the console?

Comment: Did you see some firebug/console errors?